# How do I work with a delta function that results from a Fourier Transform when trying to understand the following derivation?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

My goal is to understand a derivation in an academic article that I am having trouble wrapping my head around.

A voltage term is defined as a linear superposition of steady periodic harmonics
$V(\tilde{i}, \tilde{\omega}, t) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty V_k(\tilde{i}, \tilde{\omega} ) *exp(jk\tilde{\omega} t) + V_{-k}(\tilde{i}, \tilde{\omega})*exp(-jk \tilde{\omega} t)$

where $\tilde{\omega}$ is frequency and $\tilde{i}$ is amplitude of the current waveform.
$t$ is time.
$j$ is the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$.

The voltage coefficient are complex Fourier coefficients corresponding to each harmonic $V_{\pm k} = V_k' \pm j V_k''$

The prime denotes the real part and the double prime denotes the imaginary part.

$V(\tilde{i}, \tilde{\omega}, t)$ is multiplied by a Gaussian windowing function, $ W(t) = exp(-(\frac{\tilde{\omega} t}{2 \pi b})^2) $

Then the combined term, $V(\tilde{i}, \tilde{\omega}, t)*W(t) $  has its Fourier Transform taken

The result, according to the paper, is

$V(\tilde{i}, \tilde{\omega}, \omega) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty V_k'(G_k(\omega) + G_{-k}(\omega)) + V_k''(D_k(\omega) - D_{-k}(\omega)) + \frac{j}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty V_k''(G_k(\omega)-G_{-k}(\omega)) + V_k'(-D_k(\omega)-D_{-k}(\omega)) $

where
$ G_k(\omega) = \frac{b\sqrt{\pi}}{\tilde\omega}exp(\frac{-(\omega - k\tilde\omega)^2\pi^2b^2}{\tilde\omega^2}) $
and

$ D_k(\omega) = \frac{b\sqrt{\pi}}{\tilde\omega}exp(\frac{-(\omega - k\tilde\omega)^2\pi^2b^2}{\tilde\omega^2})*erfi(\frac{(\omega-k\tilde\omega)\pi b}{\tilde\omega}) $

here is where I get stuck

Let's just start with the first term, $V_k'(\tilde{i},\tilde\omega)*exp(jk\tilde\omega t)* exp(-(\frac{\tilde{\omega} t}{2 \pi b})^2)$ and take the Fourier Transform of that.

$F[W(t)] = \sqrt2\pi*exp(-(\pi^2b^2\omega^2)/\tilde\omega^2)*\frac{b}{\tilde\omega} $

then $F[V_k'(\tilde{i},\tilde\omega)*exp(jk\tilde\omega t)] $ = $V_k'(\tilde{i},\tilde\omega)\sqrt{2\pi}*\delta(k\tilde\omega+\omega) $ when just taking the Fourier cosine transform for the even part.

I can't get how to translate those delta functions to the resulting derivation in the paper. Any help on what I'm not understanding?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $f(t) * g(t)$ is equal to the product of the Fourier transforms of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ when $*$ denotes convolution, but not when $*$ denotes multiplication.

Comment: Hint: You might find the frequency-shifting property of the Fourier transform useful in your derivation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Modulation_/_frequency_shifting).

Comment: any other hints? I'm having a hard time taking the frequency-shifting property explanation in the wikipedia article and applying it to this particular derivation. Appreciate your help!

Comment: There are several possible definitions of the Fourier transform, and from the result above it appears you're using the definition $\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\, e^{j \omega t}\,dt$, whereas it seems the Wikipedia article is using the definition $\mathcal{F}_t[f(t)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,e^{-2 \pi j \omega t}\,dt$. You also need to make sure you're using the same definition as the academic article.

Comment: Assuming $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}_t\left[f(t)\,e^{j a t}\right](\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,e^{j a t}\,e^{j \omega t}\,dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,e^{j (\omega+a) t}\,dt=\mathcal{F}_t\left[f(t)\right](\omega+a)$, so it's just the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ evaluated at $\omega+a$ instead of $\omega$.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the authors took literal integrations from negative infinity to 0 and 0 to infinity of the fourier transform definition and then combined terms that were multiplied by the same complex coefficient.